# Error when installing Python 2 under Pyenv - Error: Unknown option '-p1'

Tags: python-2.7, pyenv

This is happening on OS X 13.6.2, with `pyenv` and `pyenv-virtualenv` installed with `brew`. This only happens when installing Python 2, Python 3.x versions all work normally. Reinstalling pyenv didn't affect anything.

```bash
$ pyenv install 3
pyenv install 3
python-build: use openssl@3 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.12.1.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.1/Python-3.12.1.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.12.1...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
Installed Python-3.12.1 to /Users/roddds/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1

$ pyenv install 2
pyenv install -v 2
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
/var/folders/3b/k8gmt0q91yn1ff71l4fk_f3w0000gp/T/python-build.20231227151924.10963 ~
Downloading Python-2.7.18.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/Python-2.7.18.tar.xz
/var/folders/3b/k8gmt0q91yn1ff71l4fk_f3w0000gp/T/python-build.20231227151924.10963/Python-2.7.18 /var/folders/3b/k8gmt0q91yn1ff71l4fk_f3w0000gp/T/python-build.20231227151924.10963 ~
Installing Python-2.7.18...
Error: Unknown option '-p1'
Usage: patch <subcommand>
  See 'patch --help' for more information.

BUILD FAILED (OS X 13.6.2 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/3b/k8gmt0q91yn1ff71l4fk_f3w0000gp/T/python-build.20231227151924.10963
Results logged to /var/folders/3b/k8gmt0q91yn1ff71l4fk_f3w0000gp/T/python-build.20231227151924.10963.log

Last 10 log lines:
/var/folders/3b/k8gmt0q91yn1ff71l4fk_f3w0000gp/T/python-build.20231227151924.10963 ~
/var/folders/3b/k8gmt0q91yn1ff71l4fk_f3w0000gp/T/python-build.20231227151924.10963/Python-2.7.18 /var/folders/3b/k8gmt0q91yn1ff71l4fk_f3w0000gp/T/python-build.20231227151924.10963 ~
```

Other potentially useful information:

- xcode tools are updated
- there's nothing else written to the error log file (python-build.20231227151924.10963.log) besides the two lines printed at the bottom of the `pyenv install 2` command output.
- `which patch` is `/usr/local/bin/patch`